# Allow only numbers in textbox in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a requirement where i need to allow only numbers in text box. if user tries to enter any other character other than numbers then we need to cancel the event. Please help me how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just have to validate the users input on a certain event. It can be e.g. on every keystroke (KeyPressEvent), when the TextBox loses focus (ValueChangeEvent), on a button press (ClickEvent), and so on. You implement an event handler, e.g. KeyPressHandler and register your implementation with the TextBox. Then in your handler you validate the TextBox value and if it contains something else than numbers, you just return from the method, probably somehow telling the user that the value was invalid.

Something like this:

```
final TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
        String input = textBox.getText();
        if (!input.matches("[0-9]*")) {
            // show some error
            return;
        }
        // do your thang
    }
});
```

If you have a lot of validation to do, you probably want to introduce some validation framework which saves you from a lot of reinventing the wheel. There may be better alternatives nowadays but personally I have been quite satisfied with the [GWT-VL validation framwork](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwt-vl/).

Comment: By the way this is pretty basic stuff and you should be able to resolve this by a little bit of googling.

Comment: Any particular reason for not using GWT ValueBox<Number>, DoubleBox, IntegerBox or LongBox with all the validation, formatting and I18N support!!!

Comment: will backspace work with this.. and navigation using Tab key..?

Comment: `LongBox` appears to let you type gibberish into the text field by default, at least in 2.5.1.  It'd be nice if there was something out of the box that provided this functionality.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this won't work because the textbox won't have the new character in in when this event fires.  I think that you should be using onKeyUp instead.

Answer (score 12):

The following is a more generic approach and allows for code reuse. You can use the NumbersOnly handler for any textbox (of the same class) you wish.

```
intbox1.addKeyPressHandler(new NumbersOnly());
intbox2.addFocusHandler(new OnFocus());


//inner class
class NumbersOnly implements KeyPressHandler {
        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            if(!Character.isDigit(event.getCharCode()))
                ((IntegerBox)event.getSource()).cancelKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: how backspace and tab key will be handled?

Comment: @knocker - This will prevent backspace, tab, copy/paste, home/end, select all and enter from working properly.  cancelKey calls preventDefault behind the scenes.  While this solution partially works, it is very limited.

Answer (score 7):

```
class NumbersOnly implements KeyPressHandler {

        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(event.getCharCode()) 
                    && event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() != KeyCodes.KEY_TAB 
                    && event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() != KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE){
                ((IntegerBox) event.getSource()).cancelKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The backspace key isn't working for me using this code in Firefox and Safari (haven't tested others) on GWT 2.5.  This also won't work with copy/paste, arrow keys, home/end or select all.

Answer (score 5):

I added other exceptions for example the possibility to copy the number. It still prevents the pasting of things from clipboard.

```
public class NumbersOnlyKeyPressHandler implements KeyPressHandler {
    @Override
    public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {

        switch(event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyCodes.KEY_TAB: 
        case KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE: 
        case KeyCodes.KEY_DELETE: 
        case KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT: 
        case KeyCodes.KEY_RIGHT: 
        case KeyCodes.KEY_UP: 
        case KeyCodes.KEY_DOWN: 
        case KeyCodes.KEY_END: 
        case KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER:
        case KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE:
        case KeyCodes.KEY_PAGEDOWN:
        case KeyCodes.KEY_PAGEUP:
        case KeyCodes.KEY_HOME:
        case KeyCodes.KEY_SHIFT:
        case KeyCodes.KEY_ALT:
        case KeyCodes.KEY_CTRL:break;
        default:

            if(event.isAltKeyDown() || (event.isControlKeyDown() && (event.getCharCode() != 'v'&& event.getCharCode() != 'V'))  )
                break;

            if(!Character.isDigit(event.getCharCode()))
                    if(event.getSource() instanceof IntegerBox)
                        ((IntegerBox)event.getSource()).cancelKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace your TextBox with either an [IntegerBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/IntegerBox.html) or [LongBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LongBox.html).

This is not semantically the same as only allowing digits, but it's arguably better in most use cases.
You will also get the in and out integer parsing done for free.

Comment: It won't prevent you from copy pasting non-numerical values, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
    if(event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode()!=KeyCodes.KEY_DELETE && 
        event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode()!=KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE &&
        event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode()!=KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT &&
        event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode()!=KeyCodes.KEY_RIGHT){
            String c = event.getCharCode()+"";
            if(RegExp.compile("[^0-9]").test(c))
                textbox.cancelKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can validate it through javascript method:

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
```

your text box will  be like this

```
<input class="txtStyle" type="text" autocomplete="off" onkeypress ="return isNumberKey(event);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The ValueBox is not primary designed to filter input.
Why? Because the user will count your app enter into ANR or corrupted when he presses keys of desktop keyboard, yes?
That s not a phone with its separated types of keyset, yes?
So the only solution here is to signal people they put in wrong characters by , e.g., red coloring. 
Let me submit an example code:

```
IntegerBox field = new IntegerBox();
        field.setStyleName("number_ok");
    field.addKeyUpHandler(event -> {
        String string = field.getText();
        char[] harfho = string.toCharArray();
        for (char h : harfho) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(""+h);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                field.setStyleName("number_error");
                return;
            }
        }
        field.setStyleName("number_ok");
    });
```

and in css:

```
.number_error{
  background-color: red;
}
.number_ok{
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (using an IntegerBox which is more or less the same thing) and did it like this;

```
    fieldName.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {            
        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            // Prevent anyone entering anything other than digits here
            if (!Character.isDigit(event.getCharCode())) {
                ((IntegerBox) event.getSource()).cancelKey();
                return;
            }
            // Digits are allowed through
        }
    });
```